# Mirroring only specific textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, mirror

To put it simply, I want my textures to be symmetrical for the most part, but I have some asymmetrical features I want to add after I've got all the base texturing down. How do I "un-mirror" the textures (without starting completely over, preferrably.)
[image: headshot]

Comment: you can use a second UV map for a second texture that you'll put over the first one

Comment: hey @moonboots i'm still having trouble with this. could i send my file over again & have you help me identify the issue?

Comment: hello you can share it with https://pasteall.org/blend/ make sure that you've packed your images before saving

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/62901d009bb840d6b17623e5f48facfc here you go. so my edits are still reflecting even tho I've tried to assign a different texture to the left & right halves of my model.

Comment: ok I've answered, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't packed your image but it doesn't matter, what I see is that in the *UV Editor*, left faces and right faces are overlapping, this is OK if you want to have a symmetrical texture. But if you want to paint something on the right side only for example you'll need to have a different UV map where left and right faces won't overlap. First thing create a new UV map in the *Object Data* panel and keep it selected:

[image]

Then select your object and, if you plan to paint in the 3D view, you can unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* method. You have assigned 2 different material to right and left but instead assign the same material (*Right_Body Material*) to both the 2 sides. In this material, create a new *Image Texture* node. Before this Image Texture, create an *Input > UV Map* node with the new UV map selected. In the *Image Texture*, create a new image with a transparent background (*Alpha* 0), mix it with the main material and use the alpha as factor:

[image]

Paint on your object, the main texture will still be symmetrized but not the new painting:

[image]

Comment: took some finessing, but i eventually got it to work! thank you so much for the help!

Comment: also i'm so sorry- in the future, do I pack my file by going to file > external data > pack all into .blend? Cos that's what I've been doing before sending it over.

Comment: yes that's it, have you done it? Because there was no texture in your file

Comment: That is how I've been doing it... must be missing a step somewhere.
Anyway- this method has been working out for me, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to keep the original UV map on the main texture only. They're overlapping on both textures atm & I'm unsure why.

Comment: You probably need activate the first UV map in the UV map list, but anyway you can plug another UV Map node into the first Image Texture if you want, and select the good UV map.

Comment: I figured it out- I had only partially unwrapped my model for the 2nd UV, so parts of it were clipping.
I've been working on this for a little while & I've  noticed that when I do it as you've got it pictured there, my 2nd texture is all white on the model & I think yours is too in the screenshots. Any reason why that is?

Comment: hello, please pack your images and share the file

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/e5b19a990779453b91dd70bcdee0e22f lmk if this is packed correctly.

Comment: first thing I notice is that your second UV Map is exactly the same, do another one, choose the Smart UV Project mode. Your second image need to be Alpha 0 (transparent), put a Diffuse after it and plug the diffuse into the Mix Shader. Plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture into the Alpha input of the Mix Shader

Comment: omg okay that did it. I hadn't unwrapped the new UV yet because I was trying to figure out this color issue, but now that it's working as intended, I'll do the unwrap. You're awesome- i really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate the symmetrical when you texturing by simply disable mesh symmetry as highlighted picture below.

[image]